# jQuery selector for intermediate string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to find all the child elements of a div that has id like:-

**child_*_of_parent**

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id=child_1_of_parent>...</div>
  <div id=child_2_of_parent>...</div>
  <div id=child_3_of_parent>...</div>
  <div id=some_other_id_1>...</div>
  <div id=some_other_id_2>...</div>
</div>
```

I want all children with ids:- **child_1_of_parent**, **child_2_of_parent**, **child_3_of_parent**

**My Try**

```
jQuery("#parent").find("div[id='child_*_of_parent']");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check starts with and ends with

Try like this

```
$("div[id ^='child_'][id $='_of_parent']")
```

Comment: Elegant Solution !!! Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome :) @Abhi same name pinch :P

Answer (score 1):

```
Try the following:

$("#parent div[id$=_of_parent][id^=child]")
```

Comment: Can you add explanations to your code? For example `id$=` means string ends with, etc. It might helps others trying to understand your solution.

Comment: Those are pretty neat selectors: [jQuery Ends With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) and [jQuery Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge it can be done be done in two ways

Matching pattern
 Here just matching the id pattern of the child elements.

```
$('#parent').children().each(function(){
   if( $(this).attr('id').match("_of_parent") ) {
        console.log($(this));
   }
});
```

Using Attribute Selector.Here checking the begining & ending pattern of the id `^` is used to check the begining of string & `$` can be used to check the ending pattern

```
var a =($("div[id ^='child_'][id $='_of_parent']"))
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/sx9a4yag/1/)

Hope this will be helpful